How to aggregate over a field which only updates on change in influxdb
I wanted to track how much my battery was discharged over the day and present it in Grafana.
Unfortunately none of my devices have any information on that.
One information I could use is the current discharge in Watts which is stored in influxdb every 20s or so, but only when it changes. Meaning, if it's 0, it doesn't get any new data points until it's discharged again.
The data is stored using ioBroker.
The problem is now, when I use aggregateWindow to get a mean every hour it only takes the number of values and doesn't consider time. So let's say at 09:00 the value is 0W, at 09:05 there is a short discharge of 500W for 30s and then it goes back to 0W for the rest of the hour and mean will now calculate something like 500/3 as the average.
My idea was to use an aggregateWindow every minute first, fill it with 0 and then do the aggregate over the hour to get Wh. Finally use a sum and divide by 1000 to get kWh.
But this seems to be very process heavy for longer periods. Is there a better way of doing this?
from(bucket: "mybucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "BatteryDischarge")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: mean, timeSrc: "_start")
  |> fill(usePrevious: true)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, timeSrc: "_start")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: sum, timeSrc: "_start")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: float(v: r._value) / 1000.0}))


If there is no better idea, I will probably add a daily task in influxdb to do this and write it into another field or bucket.
